# Get nth key value of input array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

If I have multiple html inputs all with an equal amount of array keys, but the keys are unknown, how can I get the value of the 3rd array key?

Example:

HTML

```
<input name="data[key1][key2][0]" />
<input name="data[key1][key2][1]" /> 
<input name="data[key1][key2][2]" />
```

What i'm looking for is the value of the 3rd key regardless of `[key1][key2]`. I need to get the value so I can reset indexes if an input is removed by the user.

So if a user removes the second input, the array is

```
<input name="data[key1][key2][0]" /> 
<input name="data[key1][key2][2]" />
```

I'd like to loop through the array and reset the indexes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just going to reset the index, you don't even need to get that number ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/8XEn2/))

```
$('input').each(function(i) {
    this.name = this.name.replace(/\[\d+\]$/, '[' + i + ']');
    console.log(this.name);
});
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding `$(this).attr('name', ...)` and using a vastly more efficient alternative that is also less to type. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Slice the `.name` from the last `[` to the last character.

```
this.name.slice(this.name.lastIndexOf("["), -1);
```